# Scrapy shell- correct xpath selector for getting info from a table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I'm trying to obtain the correct Xpath for extracting the information circled in red the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sPy4.png)

I've tried copying the xpath and pasting it to the scrapy shell but it isn't working. I'm having difficulties because the information is contained inside a table and every element of the table has the same  name. The website is

https://virtualmuebles.com/muebles-sala/mesa-tv-invy-1c-casa-linda-wg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text `Marca` is constant on all the pages you want to scrape. First search for a `b` element containg the text 'Marca'. Find its parent if it is a `td` element. Get the following sibling if it is a `td` element. Get its text node:

```
response.xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Marca')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/text()").get()
```

otherwise if it is always the second `td` element of the fourth `tr` element:

```
response.xpath("//tr[4]/td[2]/text()").get()
```

outputs:

```
'RTA Design'
```